# Passing a variable in the laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

How to pass a variable($test) from store to index? because I would like to display a variable in my index.blade

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('users.index', [
            'users' => User::all()
        ]);
    }
```

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User($request->all());
        $user->save();
        $test = "test";
        return redirect('users');
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. you redirect with session data  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score -1):

To resolve your problem you may edit your code like below:
index function:

```
   public function index($test=null)
    {
        return view('users.index', [
            'users' => User::all(),
            'test'  => $test
        ]);
    }
```

store function:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User($request->all());
        $user->save();
        $test = "test";
        return redirect(route('users.index', compact('test')));
    }
```

N.B: for storing your user I don't recommend to you mass assignment (new User($request->all())) when you create a new user especially if you have a password or token to store there.

Comment: Currently in index.blade {{ $test }}, I get "null".
What do I have to do to get the "test" value in index.balde {{ $test }}?

Comment: in index if you access to it directly without passing with store function it's normally you got it as null but if you accessing to the index page when you store a new value you will got 'test' as the example we have